# How to move UIButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, layout

I would like to move one UIButton from:
[image: from here]

to the bottom of the screen programmatically, how can I do that?

Comment: button.center = newPosition; ?

Comment: You can do this by changing its frame

Comment: Or buttonTopConstraint.constant = newVerticalValue; [[button superView] setNeedsLayout];

Comment: @C_X how can i change it's frame? For eg. i would like to put the "<-" button in the left corner, the "condividi" button vertically centered but in the bottom of the screen and the "->" button in the right corner! I would like to move the buttons in the bottom of the sceen!

Comment: You can do that both by manually setting frame for all three buttons, or set AutoLayoutConstraints(add constraints to > < button as well) and change constraint.constant for convidi button, reset will be handle by autolayout

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, but you can get information about the screen size as follows:

```
// Screen Sizes
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
```

You can then modify the frame or the center position of the button like this:

```
// Change frame
btnName.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/3, screenHeight/2, 100, 100)
// Change center of button
btnName.center = CGPoint(x: screenHeight/2, y: screenWidth/2)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: in viewDidLoad this doesn't work! Where should i write this code?